# Insert thin space before all page numbers (in-text citation) with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I use `biblatex` with the `apa` style.

I want to have thin spaces (`\,` or `\thinspace`) between the „p.“ and the page number, instead of the normal space which is uses by default. (Also for other languages, especially German: between „S.“ and the page number. This should be analogous.)

Is there a way to achieve this for all citations without writing `\textcite[p.\,100]{ref}` every time?

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa, backref=true]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{a,
        author = {My Testcase Author Number A},
        title  = {Test title 1.},
        date   = {2021},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\noindent
Hello \parencite[10]{a}. DEFAULT.\newline
Hello \parencite[p.\,10]{a}. MY WISH.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

PS: Having thin spaces in the backref would be great as well; however, this is not so important to me, and probably another question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command you are looking for is `\ppspace`, which by default is defined as (see [`biblatex.sty`, l. 3734 in v3.16](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/ca032db14c25fcad84a75ce5f43ba59c39ac69f2/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty#L3734))

```
\newcommand*{\ppspace}{\addnbspace}
```

If you want a non-breaking thin space, you can redefine this macro accordingly

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa, backref=true]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\ppspace}{\addnbthinspace}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Hello \autocite[10]{sigfridsson}. DEFAULT.

Hello \autocite[p.\,10]{sigfridsson}. MY WISH.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Hello (Sigfridsson & Ryde, 1998, p. 10). with a thin space between "p." and "10".]

This will apply to all languages alike and also to `backref`. If you want a language-specific definition, you need to involve `\DefineBibliographyExtras{<language>}`.